# Can other ships use the jump beacon?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

The player can now place and jump to a jump beacon inside the sector rather than the gate.  Can other player owned ships jump to a beacon?  What about NPC ships?

Comment: I read this as "jump bacon"

Comment: @OrigamiRobot sounds yummy

Comment: Woah! did not know we could place jump beacons. Was it the new update? Anyways this is good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you order your ships to jump and fly to position, they will use any available jump beacon.  However, your CAG and CLS agents will stupidly ignore jump beacons and use jump gates instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can order my ship to jump to a beacon exactly the same as to a gate. Not sure about NPC ships, though.

Comment: what about your commercial agents, will they use jump beacons automatically?

Comment: @yx.: Hmmm, I'll observe

Comment: I have a strong hunch AI ships will use beacons as well.

Comment: @kotekzot it may not be an issue with AI ships as I've observed them jumping into random positions at will, but I would really like my agents to be able to jump to a beacon that's near a complex rather than a gate and having to traverse a long distance before docking.

Comment: @spartacus I haven't played much of AP, but a lot of R and TC and i don't remember regular ships jumping into a sector not through a gate. Does this happen in any particular situation?

Comment: @kotekzot I'm surprised you haven't seen it yet, its happened in TC as well, but rarely.

Comment: @spartacus actually I seem to recall some of my transports jumping into the center of a sector to get to my massive complex that was located in a huge unclaimed sector (I reckon about 160 km from gate to gate), but otherwise they abided by regular jumpgate rules I think.